# using Maven overlay how to include shared jsp in <@ include> tag

Tags: maven, jsp, include, overlay

I have common resources war having common jsps which is included in main project pom.xml as below:

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

                            <workDirectory>target/overlay-war-folder</workDirectory>
                            <overlays>
                                    <overlay>
                                            <groupId>com.sft</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>CommonResources</artifactId>
                                             <includes>
                                                <include>**/*.jsp</include>
                                            </includes>
                                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/views</targetPath>

                                    </overlay>
                            </overlays>
                    </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I want to include jsp from commonresources war in tab as

```
<div class="tab-content">
                            <%@ include file="common.jsp"
                        </div>
```

common.jsp File not found error is popping..Do I need to include overlay folder path? How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was resolved after adding 
 runtime   in

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sft</groupId>
            <artifactId>CommonResources</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope> 
        </dependency>
```

and removing includes in overlays tag. Also my directory structure in main project under WEB-INF was different than common resources. The problem was resolved by this changes.